# How to identify a particular image in a website fetched from a particular CDN server?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

For example: There is a website which contains few images,a HTML document,and other contents. Now i want to find out the images used or displayed in the website where fetched from which CDN(Content Delivery Network) server? and likewise for HTML documents and for all contents present in the website. Can anyone help me on this one??

Comment: You could check if the url of the image is comming from a different url than the domain the html is hosted on. You could keep a list of cdn networks and test the image urls on this list. There is no perfect solution to do this, there are to many cdn's for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all the imgs / other elements that you are referencing in your code and check the domain names.  This should give you a list of items which may or may not be originating from a CDN.

```
var hosts = [];

$('img').each(function(i, e) {
    var h = $(e).attr('src').match(/^http:\/\/[^/]+/)[0];
    if (hosts[h] == undefined) hosts[h] = 0; 
    hosts[h]++;
});

console.log(hosts);
```

The above code lists all the domains for images on a page.